# Mysql result set concatenation column wise

Tags: mysql, sql

```
select * from
(select 1 )t1 join (select 2)t2 this will return result like i want 

col1 |col2
-----|----
1    |2
```

But if the inner query return more than 1 row it won't  work.

If my inner query return 2 rows like `select 1,2 union select 3,4`  then how to join with another query `select 5,6 union select 7,8` ,to get result set like below

```
col1 |col2|col3|col4
-----|----|----|----
1    |2   |5   |6
3    |4   |7   |8
```

My requirment is quite confusing.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Serious question: Have you ever read a tutorial or something about joins or sql in general?

Comment: what you want exactly, I can't understand your problem....

Comment: @fancyPants i am not sure if  i am asking something weird

Comment: @jmail i need to concatenate two result set side by side

Comment: @jasim, you should mention the which table(table name)..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd requirement but think you will need a query to generate each row, and then union those together:-

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT 1,2) t1 JOIN (SELECT 5,6) t2
UNION 
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT 3,4) t1 JOIN (SELECT 7,8) t2
```

Comment: ,ok what i asked for it gives me the result,but is it possible to get the same result with two table aliasing

Comment: I can't think of a way to do it without unioning 2 separate queries.